# Comparing Dates - date format issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, date

In my web form, I am trying to figure out the number of days off not including the weekend and holidays.  I have a SQL database where the holiday date is in date format (yyyy-MM-dd).  The user adds dates using the format MM/dd/yyyy.  Not counting weekend part of my code works.  Figuring out if a date is a holiday, and if it is, not counting it does not work.  Here is my code.  I've tried everything that is remarked out.  I appreciate any help to figure out how to compare the entered date with the SQL date.

```
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim temp As Integer

'Set same day as 1 <-- your preference. Though you can't work out averages if they are 0.
'Im not checking if this day is a holiday (though in theory you shouldn't have to!).
If StartDate = EndDate Then
    WorkingDays = 1 'Change me to your needs.
    Exit Function
End If

intCount = 0 ' Now we start counting days. 'If you always want to count the first day, set this to 1.

Do Until StartDate = EndDate

    'First, we find out if this day is a weekday or a weekend.
    'If weekday, 1 gets added to the number of days.
    Select Case Weekday(StartDate)
        Case Is = 1, 7
            intCount = intCount 'Weekend, so nothing added.
        Case Else
            intCount = intCount + 1
    End Select

    'Now, if this day was a holiday, we take it back off again!
    'Dim vsqldate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "yyyy-MM-dd", Nothing)
    'Dim vsqldate = StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    'Dim vsqldate = fromDt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim vsqldate = CDate(Format(StartDate, "yyyy-MM-dd"))

    Dim strWhere = "Holiday= #" & vsqldate & "#"  'change fieldname.

    If (DCount("Holiday", "tblCodesholidays", strWhere) > 0) Then 'Change to your field/table names.
        intCount = intCount - 1
    End If

    StartDate = StartDate.AddDays(1) 'We move to the next day.

Loop

WorkingDays = intCount
```

Answer (score 0):

From the SQL Server perspective, a date in the format 'yyyymmdd' is considered language neutral.  So, try this in your VB.Net code:

```
Dim vsqldate As DateTime 
vsqldate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
Dim strWhere = "Holiday= '" & vsqldate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") & "'"  'change fieldname.
```

Comment: How do I define vsqldate?  None of the ways I tried above worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question.  Is vsqldate a date entered on a form by the end user?

Comment: StartDate is the name of the field on the form.  I defined a variable for StartDate so I could compare it to the date field, Holiday, in the SQL table tblCodesholidays.  If StartDate = Holiday (date in table), then I don't want to count it.  FYI - I did try to define vsqldate just as StartDate, but that did not work.  Thanks for helping me!

Comment: To grab the date from the form and store it in a variable, something like this should work:

    Dim vsqldate As DateTime
    vsqldate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))

Comment: I'm getting an error "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ParseExact' accepts this number of arguments" on the vsqldate = line.  Just in case you need the function statement, it is:    Public Function WorkingDays(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As Integer

Comment: I left out a parameter--oops.  Try this:

Dim vsqldate As DateTime 
vsqldate = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: Still getting an "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ParseExact' accepts this number of arguments" on the vsqldate = line.  (Thanks for all your help with this.)